# Reseting a timer if particular condition is met?

Tags: java, timer

I have an event listener which detects when the mouse is being moved in a certain pane of my program. From this, I want to be able to perform some action if the mouse stays idle for too long.

I have looked all over earlier today, to try and find an explanation and example which details how to start, stop/cancel and reset a timer but have been bombarded with different ways to *try* and do this, which has left me quite confused.

I'm following a timer example from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/TimerScheduleataskthatexecutesonceeverysecond.htm) and implementing for my own situation

When this code below is run, it will output "A" every time the mouse stops. This is incorrect, as if I stop the mouse, move it quickly then stop it again, 2 sets of "A" are produced. 

This carries on for however many times the stop is produced.
I believe I am missing a 'reset timer' function that will called when the mouse changes to a moving state.

How can I implement this?/Is that even the problem?

```
public class SomeClass{
//...some fancy code...
    if (! isNowMoving) {
        System.out.println("Mouse stopped!");
        //Start Timer
        new PrintingA(5);
    } else if (isNowMoving){
        System.out.println("MouseMoving");

        //cancel timer & reset ready to start
    }
    public class PrintingA {
        Timer timer;

        public PrintingA(int seconds) {
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new PrintingTask(), seconds * 1000);
        }

        class PrintingTask extends TimerTask{
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("A");
                timer.cancel();
            }       
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation of `Timer`? Do you understand what each of its methods does?

Comment: Hi your approach is not appropriate. How did you predict when mouse is idle ?

Comment: @vels4j I have an event listener tied to the javaFX mouseMoved event which produces a boolean `isMouseMoving` depending on the state. What would be better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this can be useful for your requirement, Timer is a facility for threads to schedule tasks for future execution in a background thread. Tasks may be scheduled for one-time execution, or for repeated execution at regular intervals. 
Read java document : [java.util.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)

I perfer to have a thread for IdleMonitor and use [Apache Stopwatch](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/time/StopWatch.html) to monitor idle time.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.time.StopWatch;

public class IdleMonitor implements Runnable {

StopWatch stopWatch;
private final Object monitorObj = new Object();
private boolean isActive;
private long waitTime = 6000; //in milliseconds, put appropriate time to wait

public IdleMonitor() {
    isActive = true;
    stopWatch = new StopWatch();
}

public void reset() { // call this during MouseMoving event
    synchronized (monitorObj) {
        stopWatch.reset();
        monitorObj.notify();
    }
}

public void finish() { // finish idle mointor operation once your operation ends, this will stop the thread
    isActive = false;
    reset();
}

public void start() { // start monitoring
    Thread t = new Thread(IdleMonitor.this);
    t.start();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    synchronized (monitorObj) {
        stopWatch.start();
        while (isActive) {
            try {
                monitorObj.wait(waitTime);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
            long idleTime = stopWatch.getTime();
            System.out.println("Idle time " + idleTime);
            // do something if idle time beyond your expected idle time.
            // you could set isActive=false; if you want to stop monitoring
        }
    }
   }
  }

  }
```